# How do I access a property within an array from a method in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm fairly new to Vue Js and I'm trying to access a property (containing a boolean) in an array from a method so I can change the boolean on a button click but I'm not sure how to access it.

```js
export default {
  name: 'app',

  data() {
    return {

      leftImg: [
        {
          english: 'School',
          welsh: 'Ysgol',
          id: 'school',
          url: require('./img/school.jpg'),
          tag: 'left',
          displayEnglish: true,

        },
  methods: {
    changeEnglish () {
    this.leftImg.displayEnglish = false //This doesn't work
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems on the code you provided. First of all, make sure to have a correct javascript syntax. Just from your syntax, your code would look like this:

```
export default {
    name: 'app',

    data() {
        return {
            leftImg: [
                {
                    english: 'School',
                    welsh: 'Ysgol',
                    id: 'school',
                    url: require('./img/school.jpg'),
                    tag: 'left',
                    displayEnglish: true,

                }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeEnglish() {
            this.leftImg.displayEnglish = false //This doesn't work
        },
    }
}
```

Secondly, as you said in your question, the `leftImg` property is an array. So you should make sure that you specify on which index of this array you wish to update the `displayEnglish` property. In case you would like to update the first item of your array, you would have to write:

```
this.leftImg[0].displayEnglish = false
```

If it's the second, you should write

```
this.leftImg[1].displayEnglish = false
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

`leftImg` is an array. You cannot assign a value of an array element directly, so before assigning the value you should index it.

to change the first item of the array, you can use something like,

```
    this.leftImg[0].displayEnglish = false
```

But, if you are having only one item in the array, better make the `leftImg` as Object. like:

```
    data() {
      return {
       leftImg:
            {
                english: 'School',
                welsh: 'Ysgol',
                id: 'school',
                url: require('./img/school.jpg'),
                tag: 'left',
                displayEnglish: true
            }
          }
      }
```

Make the changes according to your use cases. :)